# Sumar en PHP datos enviados por AJAX en formato Json

Tags: php, javascript, json

Debo agregar X cantidad de productos a una base de datos que ya tiene productos en ella, para ella debo sumar las existencias actuales con las que quiero agregar, recibo los datos en Json perfectamente en el PHP ya que he hecho echo en cada uno de ellos y si esta funcionando, el problema es sumar lo que envio con el resultado de la consulta de los productos actuales,

veo que mi error es que hago mal manejo de json al querer sumar.

aqui el Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $("#boton_agregar_producto").click(function ()
  {
      //recogo variables a enviar al php
      var codigo_producto_a_agregar = $("#input_codigo_producto").val();
      var cantidad_a_agregar = $("#input_cantidad_a_agregar").val();
      var costo_de_cada_uno = $("#input_costo_de_cada_uno").val();
      var iva_cada_uno = $("#input_iva_cada_uno").val();

      var parametros =
      {
        "codigo_producto_a_agregar": codigo_producto_a_agregar,
        "cantidad_a_agregar": cantidad_a_agregar,
        "costo_de_cada_uno": costo_de_cada_uno,
        "iva_cada_uno": iva_cada_uno,
      }
      $.ajax({
        data: parametros,
        url: "../PHP/agregar_producto.php",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function()
        {
          $('#div_estado_busqueda_producto').html("Agregando producto...");
        },
        success: function(respuesta)
        {
           //aqui se supone que recibo la suma y por ahora la mostraria en un alert
        alert(respuesta);
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
          // Mostrar si hay error en el archivo consultar_datos_producto.php
          $('#div_estado_producto_a_crear').html(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
      });
  });
});
```

aqui el agregar_producto.php

```
<?php
require('conectar.php');
$codigo_producto_a_agregar = $_POST['codigo_producto_a_agregar'];
$cantidad_a_agregar = $_POST['cantidad_a_agregar'];

//estas dos variables las usaré luego
$costo_de_cada_uno = $_POST['costo_de_cada_uno'];
$iva_cada_uno = $_POST['iva_cada_uno'];


//compruebo algun error en la consulta, debo primero saber cuantas existencias del producto hay actualmente, no hay error en la consulta pues ya lo confirmé

if (!mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT existencias FROM productos WHERE codigo ='$codigo_producto_a_agregar'"))
{
  echo("Error de MySQL: " . mysqli_error($conexion));
}
else
{
//como no hay error, primero consulto existencias actuales para sumarlas con las que se quiere agregar
  $existencias_actuales = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT existencias FROM `productos` WHERE codigo='$codigo_producto_a_agregar'");

  //usé esta linea para probar y me sale {"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}
  //echo json_encode($existencias_actuales);

  //esta otra linea la usé para probar que pasa si hago echo solamente y sale Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in ...
  //echo ($existencias_actuales);
}

if(mysqli_num_rows($existencias_actuales) > 0)
{
  //como ya existe el producto, que debe existir por logica programada anteriormente, sumo la existencias con las que se van a agregar
  $exitencias_nueva=$existencias_actuales+$cantidad_a_agregar;

  // aqui devuelvo al ajax el resultado supuestamente, como la linea del else anterior esta mal, aqui me muestra el numero de existencias actuales, como si sumara un cero a las existencias actuales
  echo json_encode($exitencias_nueva);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tienes que convertir las cadenas de texto a enteros (o floats) para poder hacer las sumas.

Te dejo un ejemplo rápido y simplificado usando enteros con comentarios:

> HTML/JS:

```
<input type="text" id="input_codigo_producto" value="5"><br>
<input type="text" id="input_cantidad_a_agregar" value="8">
<br><br>
<button>añadir producto</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('button').on('click', () => {
        const params = {
            cod_prod: $("#input_codigo_producto").val(),
            cantidad: $("#input_cantidad_a_agregar").val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/test.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {data: JSON.stringify(params)},
            success: result => console.log(result)
        });
    });
</script>
```

> PHP:

```
if (!isset($_POST['data'])) die('faltan datos');

// $data ahora es un objeto stdClass
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);

// como todos los datos recibidos son números, podemos hacer un filtro rápido
foreach ($data as $row) {
    if (!filter_var(intval($row), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)) die('filtro no pasado');
}

// se hacen las consultas a la bd...
//$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT existencias FROM `productos` WHERE codigo='$data->cod_prod'") or die('no data');
//$existencias = intval($consulta->fetch_all()[0]);

// como ejemplo le asignamos un valor de 5
$existencias = 5;

// sumamos int + int
$existencias_nuevas = $existencias + intval($data->cantidad);

// devolvemos el resultado
echo $existencias_nuevas;
```

Comment: Si lo hago tal cual me dices, obtengo el error de filtro no pasado, alguna idea?

Comment: Si no pasa el filtro es porque se están enviando valores no numéricos.